# Why is this question protected?

Tags: support, protected-questions

Stack Overflow question *[Soundcloud Custom Player Skin not playing next tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993681)* appears to have been protected by someone, but I can't see any evidence for it. Why?

As far as I can see, it's a pretty poor question without any answers from a user who has consistently posted poor questions just containing links to his site.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like he asked the same "question" 5 times. Voted to close all 5. I'm guessing the Q-ban will take it from here.

Comment: Looking at his question scores now, that's a resounding yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the 5 deleted answers, all not actually answers, from 3 different users, all of which have less than 10 reputation.

The protection was automatic, as a result of the number of deleted answers.

Comment: Makes more sense now. Should it still be protected? Surely not?

Comment: @Liam Surely yes.  Questions that have attracted quite a few NAA answers are likely to attract more.  The users will just keep posting again and again if there is nothing to stop them.  Two of them already posted additional answers when their first was deleted.  Clearly just deleting them wasn't sufficient.

Comment: Rest assured, those same users may not be able to muster one upvoted answer to get through that barrier.